# CakePHP 3 Component in a Cell

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I created my own CakePHP 3 component. I am including it in a Controller using `$this->loadComponent()` and it works fine; however, I also need to include it in a Cell, which does not have a `loadComponent()` method.

How can I include a Component in a Cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use a component there. Because a cell is a cell and not a controller. A cell doesn't even know about the controller, check the source. http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/source-class-Cake.View.Cell.html

I think your architecture is wrong designed if you need / want to use a component inside a cell any way. Since you "forgot" to share the code it is not possible to give any further advice. Refactor your app architecture for whatever you try to do there.

Comment: I have a cell with a shopping cart; I also have a product catalog controller. Both of these locations need to do some calculations on the product prices (e.g. check if the user is logged in and pick one of the price groups, manage discounts, etc), so in my opinion, a component would do fine here. What alternative approach would you suggest? Should I move this calculation to a product model?

Comment: well, @burzum, the manual says cells are mini controller. So there are times when having a component could be useful.

Comment: @arilla I disagree, I think the book should be updated, this is misleading. It's metaphoric but not technically correct IMO. Check the code they clearly have no access to the controller. Using a component inside a cell is a MVC violation IMO and a strong indicator your architecture is not very well done. I suspect whatever hes doing is better done in a model layer class and method because it's likely data manipulation. I see cells mostly as a replacement for requestAction() if you do data manipulation inside them you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I could agree with and I alwys though that the is the whole concept of Cell that breaks the MVC. Once you let calling loadModel inside the cell you are already doing data manipulation at this point, aren't you? (note that I'm just trying to understand, don't want to start an argument, not beeing english native speaker does't help)

Comment: @arilia A cell doesn't actually allow caling `loadModel()` - you have to work around that by using TableRegistry.

Comment: @Rytis  http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.View.Cell.html#_loadModel and http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html#implementing-the-cell

Comment: My bad, sorry - confused with the Table object.

Comment: @arilia the book http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html already gives good examples for what and when to use cells. And yes, they're handy but is debatable to what extend they break or not break MVC. My bad feeling is most people won't use them properly and dump all kind of code into them.

Comment: @Rytis https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-cart-plugin I have a Cake3 version of this as well I'm working on. Your cart should be a "stupid" data store, the data can be made available by setting it always to the view. Any modification of the cart data should happen in the model. So all your component should do is set the already calculated cart to your view. There is a lot more to explain but this is not the right place to do so.

Answer (score 4):

***Would not say this is best practice but here is a quick workaround if you need to access a component from a cell.***

**In your AppController**

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;

class PageController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        Configure::write('controller', $this);
    }
}
```

**In your Cell**

```
<?php
namespace App\View\Cell;

use Cake\Core\Configure;

class ExampleCell extends Cell
{
    public function getController(){
        return Configure::read('controller');
    }
    public function display()
    {
        $data = $this->getController()->ComponentName->method();
        $this->set('data', $data);
    }

}
```

Comment: Never knew that you could write full classes into a Configure, interesting.